# Linqdatasource group by problem with multiple table

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, linqdatasource

I'm using linqdatasource for displaying data in listview (nested because of grouping) control.  I want to display data from more than one table.
I'm using VWDExpress.

Comment: After spending a lot time and rewriting from scratch a couple of times, I have rewrite it using nested data list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this solution using nested datalist controls.